# How to make dojo listener listen to newly added html fragment's event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo, fragment

Actually, I am quite new in DOJO developing. I have couple of questions to ask who had experience in DOJO development.

I had some html fragments were loaded by dojo ajax call (main html and javascript had loaded early when index.html url linkage was hit), the newly loaded fragment only update one div in whole index.html, but whole index.html kept unrefreshed.

There are some DOM elements (such as some input fields and button) in the newly loaded html fragment. I need access the fields in newly loaded html fragment by call some dojo function in my javascript. but I never get it works??

I had written some dojo script functions as DOM event listener which wait for the newly loaded  html fragment and the button was clicked, but I always get error or no response at all.

my newly loaded html fragment as:

```
<span>Enter your email to sign in</span>
<br><input type="text" placeholder="your@email.com" name="email" id="email" />
<br><input type="password" placeholder="your pass word" name="password" id="password" />
<br>
<input value="Sign in" name="Sign in" id="Sign in" class="submit" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" data-dojo-props="onClick: handleClick" data-dojo-id="dojo Sign in" type="submit" />Or<input value="Sign me up" name="Sign me up" id="Sign me up" class="submit" type="submit" />
```

and my dojo script as:

```
require(["dijit.form.Button"], function handleClick () {
  console.log("some button was clicked.");
}
);
```

and I got error message as:

```
Error: scriptError
_f()dojo.js (line 15)
req.injectUrl/_10b<()dojo.js (line 15)


...}return ret;};};var _364=function(node,root){var pn=node.parentNode;while(pn){if…
```

I totally lost, Any idea about it? appreciated.

update notes:

When I added some more require model my function looks like:

```
require(["dojo/dom",
     "dojo/on",
     "dojo/parser",
     "dijit/registry",
     "dijit/form/Button",
     "dojo/domReady!"], function handleClick () {
console.log("some button was clicked.");
}
);
```

I got other error information:

```
dojo/parser::parse() error
Error: ReferenceError: handleClick is not defined in data-dojo-props='onClick: handleClick'


throw new Error(e.toString()+" in data-dojo-props='"+_49+"'");
```

It not work as expected, suppose this function will be load to browser and then waiting for DOM element "Sign in" button was clicked, if the button not clicked, there will no script action happen, but unfortunately, the listener function was fired when the script just loaded, don't matter the click button event happen or not, it always print a String "some button was clicked." in my firebug console. Seems other any other event can trigger this action.

For the error message, it seems the script had found the caller definition from my MVC controller, it knows where is the caller. but they don't known the caller (was put in a html fragment and it will be load by a dojo ajax call, this ajax call will check the session to see weather login need or not, if need to do login, the MVC controller will send out this fragment, other wise, this fragment will never be loaded.) is not here, even not in the DOM.

I know dojo supports asynchronous function call, but how about the caller absent? or the caller will be loaded later? And this is the relationship between caller and listener, if the caller is absent, why listener works? How to make dojo listener know, caller not here or not link to the listener?

Sorry, too many questions, but it is not work as expected, so I am lost.

Comment: Please see http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/modern_dojo/ on the correct usage of `require`

Comment: Hi,Shoe, thank you for your advice. I had some update in the question section, if you have time, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Good link by @Shoe you have to look [Modern Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/modern_dojo/) again for better understanding of Dojo AMD.

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom){
  dom.byId("helloworld").innerHTML = "Hello New World!";
});
```

This is correct syntax of modern dojo coding.
Here function is called when `dojo/dom.js` is loaded. If `dom.js` calls define(), then function is not fired until `dom`'s dependencies have loaded, and the `dom` argument will hold the module value for `dojo/util`.

Comment: Hi, Mithlesh. Thank you for your advice. I will have an other test drive to see what's different. Appreciate!